# Массивы с длиной, представленной Int64

Tags: c#

Добрый день, господа! Ни для кого не секрет, что у массивов есть такое поле, как LongLength и GetValue, одна из перегрузок которого принимает long. Из этого делаем вывод, что массивы таки могут содержать в себе больше, чем int.MaxValue значений. 
Такой вывод я сделал для себя пару лет назад и успокоился, что если когда-нибудь мне понадобятся массивы с количеством значений, выписывающимся в long, это можно будет организовать. И вот, час настал. 
Мои потуги завершились на первой же строчке: int[] array = new int[longLength], где longLength имеет тип long. При компиляции все было нормально, а вот при выполнении я получаю Exception. Видимо, в создании больших массивов сокрыта какая-то тайна, о которой я прошу мне поведать

Comment: А что за Exception-то?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34413257/6766879

Comment: http://www.toolgir.ru/ispolzovanie-bolee-2gb-dlya-32-bit-prilozheniya/ Возможно информация о виртуальной памяти откроет вам глаза на то что вы пытаетесь обойти.

Comment: @Андрей Спасибо, понял. Забавно, что LongLength есть, но он бесполезен (если рассматривать одномерные массивы)

Comment: Сложно представить задачу, для который может понадобиться такой массив.

Comment: @PrimusSingularis очень даже легко. Вот есть у вас файл, который весит 4 гига. А вам нужно представить его в виде массива байтов. Путём бесхитростных математических вычислений мы получим, что нам потребуется массив длинной ~=int.MaxValue*2. Так что придётся дробить все это дело, подводим итог

Comment: @Kir_Antipov представить файл в виде массива байтов, это скорее не задача, а одно из средств решения задачи. Я к тому что какой смысл пытаться загружать весь файл в память? Можно обрабатывать файл в виде stream'ов, или читать блоками, или использовать отображение файла на память, что как раз больше подходит под ваш случай.